# Run tab name for multiple devices on Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I work on several devices with Android Studio & Flutter to test UI.

However, it's pretty confusing to know which run tab concerns which device.
All names are the same "main.dart" :

[image]

Can I display the device name stead of the main file name here?

Answer (score -1):

You can edit the Run/Debug configuration as per your need.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I want to display the device name stead of main.dart

Comment: This is not doable as of now but would love to see something like this. There's an open issue for the same. https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/4420

Comment: Yes that what I thought